# AngularJS - Confusion about directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I am confused about how to properly build custom directives - namely **when to use a controller inside a directive**. If they use an isolated scope and have properties passed to them from their parent controller this is fine.

However, seeing as I thought directives should be treated as reusable components, it makes sense to have their own controllers to set up helper methods, scope variables etc, like in a regular controller. For instance I have a custom directive and in it's template I use ng-show. The condition checks a scope property using a method I write in the **directive's controller**.

```
<div>
    <div ng-show="isLong()"></div>
</div>
```

In the directive I set up isLong in the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.isLong = function(){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Though I have not found any Angular articles about directives which talk about this use of directives. How should I be using them? And in this above example, from the directive's template how am I supposed to use ng-show?

Any guidance appreciated. I'm trying to use Angular in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

second argument not correct

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.isLong = function(){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

if you wont inject different service, you must be injectet them in array

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', ['someService', function (someService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.isLong = function(){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not talking about services.

Answer (score 0):

1. Directive controllers are executed after the compile phase. This means that by the time any directive controller function runs, *all* the directives have already been compiled and transformed.
2. A directive controller function is called before the directive (or any of its children) are linked.  This makes it a convenient place to initialize your scope before your directive is linked so that your bindings have well-defined values before their $watch handlers are called for the first time.

Remember, when you define a variable or method in your directive's scope, it is available to participate in data-binding within your directive's HTML. Child directives can also access the directive's scope as long as their scopes are set up to inherit scope prototypically - meaning a scope variable from the parent scope may be inherited by the child scope through scope inheritance.